# Dialog Close Signal

Tags: c++, qt

Can you please tell me how I can track the closing of the diolog window in Qt Creator to execute functions on the main `MainWindow`?

test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H    
#include <QDialog>    
namespace Ui {
class test;
}
class test : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit test(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~test();
private:
    Ui::test *ui;
};
#endif // TEST_H
```

test.cpp

```
#include "test.h"
#include "ui_test.h"    
test::test(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::test)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}    
test::~test()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

On the main form `MainWindow` there is a button that opens the second form:

```
void MainWindow::on_action_1_triggered()
{
    test window;
    window.setModal(true);
    window.exec();
}
```

With this design, the main window `MainWindow` is blocked, and only the `test` window is active.
I need to be able to execute some function on the main `MainWindow` when closing the `test` dialog box, for example, fill the `label` with some text, or something else. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `QDialog` it will return either `QDialog::Accepted` which is `1` or `QDialog::Rejected` which is `0`. It also returns `QDialog::Rejected` on close using `X` button. You can use its return value right away:

```
switch( window.exec() ){ 
    case QDialog::Rejected: {
        // Do stuff here
        break;
    }  
    case QDialog::Accepted: {
        // Do other stuff here
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tell me, please, I’m using such a structure, but it doesn’t work for me, the file is copied when I close the dialog box.
`void MainWindow::on_action_1_triggered()
{
    test window;
    window.setModal(true);
    switch( window.exec() ){
    case QDialog::Rejected: {
        if (QFile::exists("/tmp/test.txt"))
        {
            QFile::remove("/tmp/test.txt");
        }
    }
    case QDialog::Accepted: {
        QFile::copy(":/rec/py/test.txt", "/tmp/test.txt");
    }
    }
}`

Comment: You need to `break;` after you are done with your case. I will edit the answer.

Comment: I did as you indicated, but again the event is triggered only when the window is closed, checked with the output in `qDebug`.
`void MainWindow::on_action_1_triggered()
{
    test window;
    window.setModal(true);
    switch( window.exec() ){
    case QDialog::Rejected: {
        qDebug() << "Close";
        break;
    }
    case QDialog::Accepted: {
        qDebug() << "Open";
        break;
    }
    }
}`
Well, in principle, this will also bother me, but I would like to fully understand why the activation does not work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If the result of the dialog does not matter you can put your code after `window.exec()` otherwise you have to verify result code of this method like this:

```
if (window.exec() == QDialog::Accepted)
{
    // do your stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`QDialog` has the following signals

```
void    accepted()
void    finished(int result)
void    rejected()
```

So simply use e connect with your desired behaviour.

E.G.

```
connect(dialog, &QDialog::accepted, this, [this](){ label->setText("accepted";} ); 

connect(dialog, &QDialog::accepted, mainWindow, &MainWindow::doSomething );
```